# Is the `size` parameter for tmpfs in fstab not working?

Tags: mount, fstab, tmp, tmpfs, shm

I am confused about whether my /tmp using tmpfs is respecting the `size` parameter that I gave to it in `/etc/fstab`:

My fstab entries now read:

```
root_pool/var/tmp  /tmp /var/tmp zfs rw,nodev,nosuid 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,nodev,nosuid,noexec,nr_inodes=5k,size=2G,mode=1777 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs   defaults,nodev,nosuid,nr_inodes=5k,mode=700,size=4G 0 0
```

But according to du, it is using half of my memory (which I understand is the default) instead of the size I meant to allocate to it.

```
 ~ df /tmp
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           65921428     0  65921428   0% /tmp
```

So is the `size` parameter simply not having any effect?
I am working with Ubuntu 20.04

Edit I can mount it manually with

```
sudo mount -oremount,size=4G /tmp
```

When I do that `/tmp` is the expected 20.04 GB.

Edit: systemd status:

```
● tmp.mount - Temporary Directory (/tmp)
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (mounted) since Wed 2020-06-17 13:30:35 EDT; 8min ago
      Where: /tmp
       What: tmpfs
       Docs: https://systemd.io/TEMPORARY_DIRECTORIES
             man:file-hierarchy(7)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 154317)
     Memory: 76.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/tmp.mount

Jun 17 13:30:35 virtland systemd[1]: Mounting Temporary Directory (/tmp)...
Jun 17 13:30:35 virtland systemd[1]: Mounted Temporary Directory (/tmp).
```

and `journalctl -u tmp.mount`

```
-- Reboot --
Jun 17 13:27:50 virtland systemd[1]: tmp.mount: Directory /tmp to mount over is not empty, mounting an>
Jun 17 13:27:50 virtland systemd[1]: Mounting Temporary Directory (/tmp)...
Jun 17 13:27:50 virtland systemd[1]: Mounted Temporary Directory (/tmp).
Jun 17 13:29:43 virtland systemd[1]: Unmounting Temporary Directory (/tmp)...
Jun 17 13:29:43 virtland systemd[1]: tmp.mount: Succeeded.
Jun 17 13:29:43 virtland systemd[1]: Unmounted Temporary Directory (/tmp).
-- Reboot --
Jun 17 13:30:35 virtland systemd[1]: tmp.mount: Directory /tmp to mount over is not empty, mounting an>
Jun 17 13:30:35 virtland systemd[1]: Mounting Temporary Directory (/tmp)...
Jun 17 13:30:35 virtland systemd[1]: Mounted Temporary Directory (/tmp).
```

Edit2: Setting the size of tmpfs for `/dev/shm` is working as expected:

```
# in fstab
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs   defaults,nodev,nosuid,nr_inodes=5k,mode=700,size=4G 0 0
```

```
tmpfs                                  13184288       2328   13181960   1% /run
tmpfs                                   4194304      41056    4153248   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                      5120          4       5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                                  65921432          0   65921432   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                                  65921432          0   65921432   0% /tmp
tmpfs                                  13184284          8   13184276   1% /run/user/1000
```

Also, it seems that the noexec option, although recommended by many security guides, is problematic because some programs (including apt) need to execute from /tmp. I understand that this can be gotten around, but I don't want to have to figure out every program that needs to be an exception.

Comment: What is your OS version? does the value take effect if you remount (ex. `sudo mount -oremount,size=4G /tmp`)?

Comment: 20.04, and yes manually mounting with the size specification works as expected, makint `/tmp` 4 GB in size.

Comment: Hmm... do `journalctl -u tmp.mount` and/or `systemctl status tmp.mount` throw any light on the matter?

Comment: I'm not sure that it does, but I have added the output to my questions.

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of the two lines (so `/dev/shm` comes before `/tmp`) and restarting? (the first line looks suspicious to me)

Comment: @tfstwbbnb I just tried that and it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ubuntu 20.04 the unit `tmp.mount` originally lives in `/usr/share/systemd/tmp.mount`.

Modifications done by the system administrator (user) go into `/etc/systemd/system/` which is probably why these have higher priority.

I'm not sure why your unit resides in `/etc/systemd/system/`.

My guess is that your `tmp.mount` unit in `/etc/systemd/system/` is interfering with the entry in fstab.

To confirm this change the following line in `/etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount`

```
Options=mode=1777,strictatime,nosuid,nodev
```

into

```
Options=mode=1777,strictatime,nosuid,nodev,size=YOURSIZE
```

To get the behaviour you desire, disable and remove the unit defined in `/etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount`.

Comment: Yes! That did it!. The `/tmp` directory now shows as a filesystem of the size I set it to in `/etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount`.

Comment: A good answer but I think [this similar answer on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352048/161288) is a bit better.